# How to use two healthchecks in docker-compose file where the python app depends on both healthchecks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two postgres containers one mdhillon/postgis and another postgrest/postgrest. And the python app depends on both the healthchecks of the postgres containers. Please help

In terminal after docker-compose up

```
Creating compose_postgis_1 ... done
Creating compose_postgrest_1 ... done


Error for app Container <postgrest_container_id> is unhealthy. And the terminal exits
```

Showing docker-compose.yml file

```
services:
  postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  postgrest:
    image: postgrest/postgrest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    environment:
      PGRST_DB_URI: postgres://${PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE}:@postgis:5432/postgres
      PGRST_DB_SCHEMA: ${PGRST_DB_SCHEMA}
      PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE: ${PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE}
      PGRST_DB_POOL: ${PGRST_DB_POOL}  
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  app:
    image: newapp
    command: python main.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      postgis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgrest:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the official Postgres Docker Image, there is an option to RUN your postgres on a specific port. You need to add ENV variable `PGPORT` for postgree docker container to run on a different port. Try the below one...

```
services:
  postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  postgrest:
    image: postgrest/postgrest
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:cached
    environment:
      PGRST_DB_URI: postgres://${PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE}:@postgis:5432/postgres
      PGRST_DB_SCHEMA: ${PGRST_DB_SCHEMA}
      PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE: ${PGRST_DB_ANON_ROLE}
      PGRST_DB_POOL: ${PGRST_DB_POOL}
      PGPORT: 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
  app:
    image: newapp
    command: python main.py
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      postgis:
        condition: service_healthy
      postgrest:
        condition: service_healthy
```

By default, Postgres container runs on Port 5432 inside Docker Network. Since, you are not changing the port of Postgres Container, both the containers are trying to run on same port inside docker network, and due to this, one container will run and the other will not. You can check the logs of docker container for better understanding.

Hence, adding `PGPORT` env var to the container to run Postgres on diff port will resolve your issue...

Comment: Failing. Again same error. Please help. One healthy-postgis. postgrest unhealthy. App breaks. terminal exits. Thank you for replying

Comment: Can you get the docker container logs for the failed postgres Container?